# Wordpress keeps prompting me to convert page layout to the new Visual Composer version after converting

Tags: wordpress, backslash

As I begin to edit one of my pages, I get this message: "Your page layout was created with previous Visual Composer version. Before converting your layout to the new version, make sure to read this page." So I accept, and it converts without any noticeable errors.
However, even after publishing changes and I try to edit the page again, the same message appears as if it never converted it.

Another issue is that Wordpress keeps adding backslashes. It seems to be doing that to create escape characters for quotes and such. Could it be adding these backslashes each time it 'converts'

Any suggestions or tips to fix these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which template?  I think its a template issue. WordPress doesn't have visual composer built in. Only a visual editor.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress 4.1 with the Impreza theme

Comment: Its unique problem to the theme. If you bought it, open a ticket by the support, that why i do when i have issues that are specific to the template.

Comment: Alright will do. Thanks!